# GCP Dataproc Deletion Protection

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a bash script to create dataproc clusters in GCP and was wondering if it was possible to add deletion protection in that same script so that deletion protection is enabled by default. I've tried adding --deletion-protection to the script but get this error:

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataproc.clusters.create) unrecognized arguments: --deletion-protection

Answer (score 0):

Deletion protection is not a supported feature as of Q3 2022, they might add it in the future.